# Reinitialise jQuery booklet plugin after page load

Tags: jquery, plugins, initialization

Ref: jQuery booklet - http://builtbywill.com/code/booklet/options

I'm using the jQuery booklet plug-in with a custom options hash:  (e.g. `$(elem).booklet({props: values})`).

**Current options**:

When closed is set to true the page loads with the book closed as desired, however the closed true option also closes the book when the end of the book is reached.

**Desired requirement**:

1. I need to load the page with the book closed
2. Leave the book open on a 2-page spread when the end of the book is reached (still providing the facility to turn pages towards the front of the book)

Any help/advice with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One of the options is to add a blank image as first page. That would simulate it as a only one page on right. We can of course make changes to the script to achieve this, but I think this is the quickest way. Let me know if this works.